# How to automatically add group members to slack channel that fits a certain REGEX

Tags: slack

Whenever there is a channel with the name that matches a certain regex, we want to add a certain group of members to these channel automatically. For example, if a new slack channel with the name that matches the regex INC-.* is created, slack group @incidentmembers will be added to that new slack channel automatically

Is there a way to configure this in Slack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no native way to do this in Slack, but you could build something using the public APIs. Specifically you would

- Listen to the [`channel_created`](https://api.slack.com/events/channel_created) event which fires when a public channel is created, which you can then regex as you see fit.
- Grab the membership of the relevant User Group using [`usergroups.users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/usergroups.users.list) (if the membership is static you could probably skip this)
- Use [`conversations.invite`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.invite) to add the users to the channel

One limitation of this approach is that you won't get `channel_created` events for private channels. There's no way around this I'm afraid.